# Spring MVC + Spring Hadoop memory leak on tomcat reload

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hadoop, spring-data

I'm looking to use [spring for apache hadoop](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hadoop/) and spring MVC to write a servlet that interacts with hadoop.  Since hadoop-core has dependencies on jetty and tomcat I needed to exclude them as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423883/jsp-servlet-exception)

I'm trying to use spring to create an `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` object like this

```
<hdp:configuration file-system-uri="hdfs://localhost:9000"/>    
<hdp:file-system/>
```

then autowire it into a controller like this

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired FileSystem hdfs;
```

File system operations work as expected but tomcat reports a memory leak on servlet reload:

```
Feb 11, 2015 4:14:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/hadoopsync] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil$1] (value [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil$1@38504b85]) and a value of type [java.util.Random] (value [java.util.Random@1f8e25a5]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Feb 11, 2015 4:14:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/hadoopsync] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.hadoop.io.Text$1] (value [org.apache.hadoop.io.Text$1@2d4983d2]) and a value of type [sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.Encoder] (value [sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder@356d6738]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

After a couple of reboots tomcat blows up with an out of memory exception. I've tried explicitly calling both`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.close()` and `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.closeAll()` in a `@PreDestroy` method, passing additional args to spring config like this `<hdp:file-system close="true" close-all="true"/>`
and manually getting and closing a file system object like this

```
@Autowired Configuration config;
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    //immediately getting, then closing an object still results in a leak
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
    fs.close(); //also tested closeAll here
}
```

I'm not quite sure if there is another strategy for getting hadoop / spring-hadoop to manage lifecycle methods inside a servlet or if I'm trying to use these libraries together in an unreasonable way. I was unable to find any examples of spring-hadoop inside a servlet [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples) and the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/index.html) didnt cover it either. Are there any other ways of getting a servlet to talk to hadoop?

Comment: Using the tomcat manager to do redeploys always gave us memory leaks of all kinds in different parts of our code that we wasted a lot of time trying to solve, totally without success. We just gave up using the tomcat manager and only did complete restarts. (And of course invested in JRebel).